Irrationality of numbers that are the sum of reciprocal factorials, like $e.$
I wish to prove that for any infinite $A\subset \mathbb{N},\ \displaystyle\sum_{k\in A} \frac{1}{k!}$ is irrational, in the same manner that Rudin proves $e$ is irrational. I should mention the trivial case where $\vert\mathbb{N}\setminus A\vert$ is finite, for then $\displaystyle\sum_{k\in A} \frac{1}{k!} = \left(e-\frac{1}{0!}\right) - \sum_{k\in (\mathbb{N}\setminus A)} \frac{1}{k!}, $ which is $e$ subtract a rational number and is therefore irrational.
Rudin's proof that $e:= \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}$ is irrational goes as follows.

Define $ \displaystyle s_n:= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}.\ $ Then, $e - s_n = \displaystyle\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} < \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\left\{ 1 + \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)^2} + \ldots \right\} = \frac{1}{n!n},\ $
so that
$$ 0 < e-s_n < \frac{1}{n!n}. \tag{1}\label{eq1} $$
Now suppose $e$ is rational, that is, $e=p/q,$ where $p,q$ are positive integers. By $\eqref{eq1},$
$$ 0 < q!(e-s_q) < \frac{1}{q}. \tag{2}\label{eq2} $$
By our assumption, $q!e$ is an integer. Since
$$ q!s_q = q!\left( 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \ldots + \frac{1}{q!} \right) $$
is an integer, we see that $q!(e-s_q)$ is an integer. Since $q\geq 1,\ \eqref{eq2}\ $ implies the existence of an integer between $0$ and $1.$ We have thus reached a contradiction.

Now onto my attempted proof that for an infinite $A\subset \mathbb{N},\ f:= \displaystyle\sum_{k\in A} \frac{1}{k!}$ is irrational. First, write $A$ as an increasing sequence of integers: $A = \left( a_k \right)_{k=1}^{\infty}.$ Define $ \displaystyle t_n:= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_k!}.\ $ Then,
$$f - t_n = \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_k!}< \frac{1}{a_{n+1}!}\left\{ 1 + \frac{1}{(a_{n+1}+1)(a_{n+1}+2)\cdots a_{n+2} } + \frac{1}{(a_{n+1}+1)(a_{n+1}+2)\cdots a_{n+2}(a_{n+2}+1)\cdots a_{n+3} } +  \ldots \right\}.$$
Since $a_n \geq n$ and $a_{n+1}>a_n,$ we can certainly say that $0 < f - t_n < \frac{1}{n!n}$ by comparison with the reasons given for $\eqref{eq1},$ although this inequality is weak and could be improved.
But then if we continue the proof similar to irrationality of $e,$ that is, suppose $f=p/q,\ p,q$ are integers. Then $0 < q!(f-t_q) < \frac{1}{q}$ is true, but there are problems in the next statement: we cannot say $q!t_q = q!\left( \frac{1}{a_1!} + \frac{1}{a_2!} + \ldots + \frac{1}{a_q!} \right) $ is an integer.
Alternatively, $a_q!t_q$ is an integer, although I don't see how to use this to make an equation like equation $\eqref{eq1}.$
Have I made a mistake somewhere? If not, is there a way to make some progress here and prove my desired statement? I do feel like I'm missing something relatively obvious.

Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1324206/the-irrationality-of-rapidly-converging-series?rq=1

Interestingly, I think the set of all such numbers, that is, the set $S:= \left{\displaystyle\sum_{k\in A} \frac{1}{k!} : A\subset\mathbb{N}\right}$ is a perfect set, although this would be more "interesting" if this contained only irrational numbers, which it doesn't, since $S$ allows for $\vert A \vert <\infty.$

It is correct that $0 < f - t_n < \frac{1}{n!n}$, but the upper bound can be improved:
$$
\begin{align}
 0 < f - t_n &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{a_{n+1+k}!} \\
 &\le \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(a_{n}+1+k)!} \\
 & < \frac{1}{(a_{n}+1)!} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(a_n+1)^k} \\
&= \frac{1}{a_n! \cdot a_n} \, .
\end{align}
$$
And then assuming that $f=p/q$ is rational gives a contradiction:
$$
 0 < a_q! (f -t_q) < \frac {1}{a_q}
$$
since $a_q! (f -t_q)$ is an integer.

You can often use the same technique as for e.
Assume the sum is p/q, and that it is the sum of integers divided by n!. So the sum of terms with factorials up to q! is an integer divided by q!. If you can show that the sum of the remaining terms multiplied by q! is between 0 and 1 or possible between two other integers, then the sum is irrational.
Take the sum of $n^2 / n!$ as an example and assume it is p/q. The next terms multiplied by q! would be $(q+1)^2 / (q+1)$ = q+1, an integer, followed by $(q+2)^2 / ((q+1)(q+2))$ = $1 + 1 / (q+2)$, and the remaining terms are roughly 1/q, 1/q^2 etc. So the sum of the remaining terms multiplied by q! is strictly between q+2 and q+3 and not an integer, so the complete sum is irrational.
If the sum is not over all n but only n in some subset A, just replace the missing terms with $0 / n!$. If A is finite then you add a finite number of rationals, which is rational. Otherwise you need to show that the sum of terms with n > q, multiplied by q!, is strictly between two integers. And in the case that you want to show this for any infinite set A, you need to show that any such sum is strictly between two integers. That's true in the case of $n^2 / n!$.
